# Samsung induction slide in oven makes whining and whistling noise

Tags: oven, noise

My Samsung induction stove/oven that is only 1.5 years old started making a whining and whistling noise when on Bake. I think it's a fan, but this noise wasn't there before. What can it be and is it dangerous not to fix it right away and keep using it? Thank you!

Comment: What's the model number?

Comment: @Victoria you never stated model or if it is convection or if it was during baking only or if you were cooking on the stove top at the same time. I have a Samsung Induction oven and have repaired mine. See my answer.

Comment: @Victoria Did you get your issue resolved and if so could you update here by editing so others might know as well. Just going on my experience I am thinking the fan gave out and the oven took forever to get up to temp.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

You say when on Bake - is it a convection oven ?

I have a slide in Samsung Induction Stove / Oven.

So I want to be sure of what you are describing - only when the oven is operating or are you using the cook top at the same time ?

Depending on your answer I will give you a couple possibilities.

```
1: The induction cooktops can make a noise while cooking - you will
notice this when it gets hot you can hear a whine and a whir (like a
zzzzzrr) sound .  

2: The Fan in the rear of the oven (its the circulation fan) the
bearings fail! I know I replaced mine after 1 year - many others
have also.
```

> Will it hurt anything is it dangerous not to fix it right away:
>
> Depends on if you like your cake and your foods thoroughly cooked or
>   on the raw side. And also on How Long you want it to take to preheat
>   to the right temperature.

How this oven works: During preheat all fans run to circulate the air, all elements are on to heat up quickly - upon reaching temperature the oven converts to the mode of operation you have selected whether that is bake or convection etc..

Now if the fan is failing - the oven will start to take longer and longer to get up to temperature - also opening the door the temperature will drop and not recover quickly.

One thing to do is use a manual oven thermometer and place it inside your oven - watch what temperature it gets to - it might claim it is hot enough in the beginning because the temp probe is right next to the Broiler Element up top. NICE - it measures the radiated heat from that burner, not the oven temp - so you get a claim it is at temp. Open the door and the temp will drop - since the broiler element does not come back on at that moment - well long time heating back up.

The Fan is simple to replace - get an after market one - my after market one has been in for 2 years now and so far the thing works - but we also do not run the self cleaning or broiler - high temperatures might damage the fan bearings or the lube in those bearings. Personally this oven is the worst I have ever owned. I love the induction stuff - but other manufacturers have more flexibility and are not as finnicky about the pans. We have Caphalon Stainless Steel. Not clad bottoms.

Comment: Lots of ovens don't have fans you just need to adjust baking times. Depending on the type of motor it can overheat and cause other problems if the bearings fail, If a shaded pole motor it won't hurt anything other than not having the convection feature.

Comment: @EdBeal I have the service manual for the samsung oven and I also have the oven (repaired it once already) many others have the same exact issue - if the convection fans don't work the oven will not come up to temperature (or if they barely work - it will take MUCH longer to come up to temperature). The method of operation in any mode is :  run all heat elements and the circulation fans in order to get the oven up to the set temperature, after the oven reaches the set temperature the cooking mode determines which elements to keep on and if the fans will run or not.